# Java: JDBC get Column Constraints

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Currently using JDBC I am able to retrieve column information from tables in my database. I am able to retrieve the name, column type and if the column allows null values.

However I'm trying to retrieve if the column has any constraints, specifically the Unique constraint.

Code:

```
rs = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
while (rs.next()) {
    String columnName = rs.getString(4);
    String TypeName = rs.getString(6);
    String nullable = rs.getString(18);
```

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation of [`DatabaseMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) for what information the API provides.

Answer (score 1):

Column uniqueness is typically handled by an index.  Try the `DatabaseMetData.getIndexInfo()` method.  You also might want to check the `DatabaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys()` results.